# How can I change Button color via a trigger in the button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

Whats wrong with this trigger? I found it here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/ and ive seen similar setups on SO

```
    <Button x:Name="ColorPickerButton" Background="{Binding SelectedColor}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Im trying to break down my spaghetti XAML and make it more readable. This is my old implementation which does work. I dont like it because it overwrites the button content and overlays a border which seems unnecessary. Also its massive

```
    <Button x:Name="ColorPickerButton" Background="{Binding SelectedColor}">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <GridViewRowPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ColorPickerButton.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Trigger does not work because the **default Template** of the button has its own trigger that changes the background brush of the root border when the *IsMouseOver* Property is set. This means: As long as the mouse is on top of the button, the *Background*-property of the button control will be ignored by its template.

The easiest way to check out the default style of your button is to: right-click at the button in the visual studio wpf designer. Click '*Edit template*' -> '*Edit a copy*' and select a location. 
A copy of the default style is created at the specified location. You will see a trigger like this:

```
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
   </Trigger>
```

On top of designer created style definition it also created the brushes that are used within the style:

```
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
```

You can either change these brushes or the *Value* property of the setters above to change the background when the mouse is over. 
Or you create your own Template like you did in your old implementation.